Kotlin sending mail with gmail gives 400 Precondition check failed
When I am sending email with Gmail I get error message FAILED_PRECONDITION:
Google API error during email send: {
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Precondition check failed.",
      "reason": "failedPrecondition"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Precondition check failed.",
  "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
POST https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Precondition check failed.",
      "reason": "failedPrecondition"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Precondition check failed.",
  "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}

I have stored the service account key in a json file named service-account-key.json:
{
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "client_email": "x@y.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "1234",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/x.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\12234556\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "private_key_id": "abcde",
  "project_id": "z",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "type": "service_account"
}

My SendMessage.kt class looks like this:
package com.x.email

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials
import jakarta.mail.MessagingException
import jakarta.mail.Session
import jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*

object SendMessage {

    @JvmStatic
    @Throws(MessagingException::class, IOException::class)
    fun sendEmail(fromEmailAddress: String, toEmailAddress: String): Message? {
        println("Starting sendEmail process...")
        var service: Gmail? = null
        try {
            // Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
            println("Loading Google credentials...")
            val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(FileInputStream("service-account-key.json"))
                .createScoped(listOf(GmailScopes.GMAIL_SEND))
            print("credentials=$credentials")

            val requestInitializer: HttpRequestInitializer = HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials)

            // Create the Gmail API client
            println("Creating Gmail service...")
            service = Gmail.Builder(
                NetHttpTransport(),
                GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                requestInitializer
            )
                .setApplicationName("Gmail samples")
                .build()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            System.err.println("Failed to initialize Gmail service: ${e.message}")
            e.printStackTrace()
            return null
        }

        // Create the email content
        val messageSubject = "Test message"
        val bodyText = "lorem ipsum."

        val email: MimeMessage = try {
            println("Creating email content...")
            val props = Properties()
            val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
            MimeMessage(session).apply {
                setFrom(InternetAddress(fromEmailAddress))
                addRecipient(jakarta.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress(toEmailAddress))
                subject = messageSubject
                setText(bodyText)
            }
        } catch (e: MessagingException) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create email content: ${e.message}")
            e.printStackTrace()
            return null
        }

        // Encode and wrap the MIME message into a Gmail message
        val message: Message = try {
            println("Encoding email to Gmail Message format...")
            val buffer = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            email.writeTo(buffer)
            val rawMessageBytes = buffer.toByteArray()
            val encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(rawMessageBytes)
            println("Encoded Email Content: $encodedEmail")
            Message().apply { raw = encodedEmail }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            System.err.println("Failed to encode email: ${e.message}")
            e.printStackTrace()
            return null
        }

        return try {
            // Send the message
            println("Sending email...")
            val sentMessage = service?.users()?.messages()?.send("me", message)?.execute()
            println("Message sent successfully with ID: ${sentMessage?.id}")
            sentMessage
        } catch (e: GoogleJsonResponseException) {
            System.err.println("Google API error during email send: ${e.details?.toPrettyString()}")
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            System.err.println("Unexpected error during email send: ${e.message}")
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }
}

This is my Main.kt which uses SendMessage.kt:
package com.x

import com.x.email.SendMessage
import jakarta.mail.MessagingException


fun main() {


    println("Email test:")
    val fromEmail = "from@mydomain.com"
    val toEmail = "me@mydomain.com"

    try {
        val sentMessage = SendMessage.sendEmail(fromEmail, toEmail)
        if (sentMessage != null) {
            println("Email sent successfully!")
            println("Message ID: ${sentMessage.id}")
        } else {
            println("Failed to send email.")
        }
    } catch (e: MessagingException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        println("Error in creating the email: ${e.message}")
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        println("Error in connecting to Gmail API: ${e.message}")
    }
}

I do not know if this has something to do with my build.gradle.kts?
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.20"

}

group = "com.x"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral() // Default Maven repository
    maven {
        url = uri("https://maven.google.com") // Google Maven repository
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Google Cloud Secret Manager
    implementation("com.google.cloud:google-cloud-secretmanager:2.54.0") // Read secrets
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0") // JSON parsing
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.14") // HTTP requests
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.3.0") // Excel

    // Gmail API
    implementation("com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.33.2") // Compatible with Gmail API
    implementation("com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.14.0") // Matches Google API Client
    implementation("com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev20211108-1.32.1")
    implementation("commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15") // Base64 encoding
    implementation("com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0") // Attachments
    implementation("com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:2.0.1") // Mail implementation

    // Test dependencies
    testImplementation(kotlin("test")) // Kotlin test framework
}




tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.x.MainKt" // Replace with your main class
    }
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(20)
}


Not a Kotlin developer. APIs Explorer is a good way to test/debug services e.g. Gmail's send method. I suspect (!?) it's your use of a Service Account unless this is domain-wide delegated. Workspace APIs require user credentials or DWD to operate on user-owned data.
